# Print in Value order, or if values are the same, alphabetical order

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a 'Vowel Counter', but I would like it to satisfy the following conditions.

It prints the letter, followed by the value, in order of largest value to lowest.
But if two values are the same, it prints them in alphabetical order.

Here is my code with two ways of getting the values in order.  The problem is, 'i' always prints before 'e' if they're the same value?  As well as this, it doesn't print the '0' letters.

```
from collections import Counter
vowels = 'aeiou'

def vowel_counter(string):
    count = Counter(letter for letter in string if letter in vowels)
    return count

while True:
    string = raw_input().lower()
    if string == 'exit':
        break
    x = vowel_counter(string)
    ##This is a basic method to print all the vowels and their values
    print "basic method: ",
    for vowel in vowels:
        print vowel + ":" + str(x[vowel]),
    print
    ## This is the method using sort
    sorter = [(value,key) for key,value in x.iteritems()]
    sorter.sort(reverse=True)
    print "sort method: ",
    for a,b in sorter:
        print "%s:%d" % (b,a),
    print
```

Here is some sample Input/Output

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Phasellus malesuada erat sed venenatis consequat.
exit
basic method:  a:2 e:5 i:6 o:4 u:2
sort method:  i:6 e:5 o:4 u:2 a:2
basic method:  a:7 e:7 i:1 o:1 u:3
sort method:  e:7 a:7 u:3 o:1 i:1
```

Any ideas as to how to get it to print out correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
" ".join("{}:{}".format(v, x[v]) for v in sorted(vowels, key=x.get, reverse=True))
```

This uses the fact you have `vowels = "aeiou"` in the pseudo order you want and sorts this 'string' based on value `x.get` in the dictionary. This gives you the key order you need to extract the items from the dictionary.
If you didn't have `vowels` you could replace with `sorted(x)`, i.e. sort the keys first then sort by value.

Output:

```
{'a':2, 'e':5, 'i':6, 'o':4, 'u':2} -> i:6 e:5 o:4 a:2 u:2
{'a':7, 'e':7, 'i':1, 'o':1, 'u':3} -> a:7 e:7 u:3 i:1 o:1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I'm not really sure how it works so if you could explain that, that would be great.  Otherwise, this works perfectly.